# Cleaning minimum tables

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms

John has been newly hired to clean tables at his restaurant. So whenever a customer wants a table, he must clean it.

But John happens to be a lazy boy. So in the morning, when the restaurant is opened, all the tables are dirty from night before.

The customer don't leave the table unless they are politely requested to do so. And customers can order meal later again. So if they were already having a table, they can be served on the same table [John doesn't have to clean]. But if they don't have a table then they must be given some table [John must clean]

**Problem :**

The restaurant has N tables. When a customer requires a table, he/she can occupy any unoccupied table. However if all tables are occupied, then John is free to ask politely any customer to leave his/her table. And the freed table can be given to the waiting customer.

**Now Given the  list telling the order of customer meal requests for the entire day, 
we need to find find the minimum number of times he has to clean the tables.**

**Example 1 :** Let their are 2 tables that mean N=2 and their are 4 order that means M=4 and list showing the  order in which customers ask for meal is [1 2 3 4]

Then here answer is 4

**Explanation :** In the starting all tables i.e. 2 tables are unoccupied. 
When customer 1 asks for table, he can be given any of the 2 tables. 
John has to clean either of the table. Next customer 2 can occupy the other free table. John must clean second time. When customer 3 comes John can ask either customer 1 or 2 to leave. Suppose he asks customer 1 to leave. Then he has to clean table for the third time. When customer 4 comes, he can ask customer 2 or 3 to leave. In either case He will have to clean the table for the fourth time.

**Example 2:** Let N=3 and M=5 and list be [1 2 1 3 4]

Then here answer will be 4.

**Explantion :** Suppose the tables are listed as [-, -, -]. A possible optimal order of allocating tables can be [1, -, -] -> [1, 2, -] -> [1, 2, -] -> [1, 2, 3] -> [4, 2, 3]. So John will have to clean table for order no. 1, 2, 4 and 5. That is 4 times.

Comment: It's hard to find the Question in this narrative.

Comment: @hardmath The uestion to find minimum number of times John has to clean the tables

Comment: Why doesn't John need to clean the table for order #3 in example 2?

Comment: @Charles No he dont need to clean table in Order#3 as you can see 1 has already having table and third order is by 1 again.

Comment: @user3878046: How do we know that?

Comment: @Charles Its mentioned in the list of orders which is [1 2 1 3 4].Means Order by 1 is repeated at Order#3

Comment: A brief narrative to motivate the problem is nice, but if a Reader has to sort through the narrative to find out the inputs that constrain the solution, it's discouraging.  It's almost like you expect the Reader to parse your examples and tell you what the problem formulation should be.

Comment: As somebody posted as an answer, this seems to be a problem in an ongoing competition: http://www.codechef.com/AUG14/problems/CLETAB